# Solving a set of two coupled nonlinear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equations are: $\ddot{r} - r \ddot{\varphi}^2=0$ and $\ddot{\varphi} + \frac{2}{r}\dot{r}\dot{\varphi}=0$. I unfortunately have no clue how to go about solving this.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: He is asking for a general solution so no boundary condition is needed.

Answer (score 2):

$\ddot{\varphi}+\frac{2}{r}\dot{r}\dot{\varphi}=0 \; \Rightarrow \;  \dot{(r^2\dot{\varphi})}=0 \; \Rightarrow \; \dot{\varphi}= \frac{c}{r^2}$, where $c$ is a constant.

Then the other given equation becomes,

$ \ddot{r} = r \left(\frac{4}{r^2}\dot{r}^2\dot{\varphi}^2 \right) = \frac{4 c^2 \dot{r}^2}{r^5}$

First solve $ \ddot{r} = \frac{4 c^2 \dot{r}^2}{r^5} $  for $v = \dot{r}$ in the following way,

$ \ddot{r}=\dot{v} = v \frac{dv}{dr}$ and then solve for $ v \frac{dv}{dr}= \frac{4 c^2 v^2}{r^5} $

Comment: Almost impossible to find a solution in terms of $t$ (or wichever the variable we are differencing versus is called).

Comment: @N74 Why do you think it is impossible? At least Mathematica can give a solution to it. :)

Comment: Mybe for $t$ as a function of $r$, but then to invert, substitute and find a solution to $\varphi$ we will need the genius of Ramanujan :D.

Comment: That would be too easy for him. :P